# Derive the recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

Either this question is the easiest one on StackExchange or I just don't get it. The question is :

**"Let F(n) be the number of strings of length n over an alphabet of size k. Derive a recurrence relation for F(n)."**

Clearly, $ F(n)=k^n $ since for every 'letter' we have k choices and there are n letters. And also F(0) = 1 and F(1) = k.
How to derive a recurrence relation for this?
Thank you in advance and be safe.

Comment: $F(n+1) = F(n)*k$, is that all they want?

Comment: yeah it is. I knew that it was smth very easy that I was just missing! thank you very much